# Пропустить символы в Цикле, си

Tags: c

Дан текст "for    (anything)" 
Как пропустить все что перед '(' и ')',т.е **перед первой скобочкой могут быть сколько угодно пробелов,а внутри скобочек все что угодно**
 *главное чтобы была открывающая и закрывающая скобки,не обращая внимания что внутри*

Comment: Вот как надо задавать вопросы!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все равно быстрее чем пробежаться по массиву циклом с начала до первой ")" после "(" вы ничего не придумаете. Библиотечные функции не сработают быстрее, только на вызове время потеряете. Просто бежим циклом, встретили "(" ставим флажок, встретили ")" проверяем флажок, если есть все стоп.

```
int i  = 0;
int flag = 0;
for (i = 0 ; i < lenght; i++)
{
  if(str[i] == '(')
    flag = 1;
  if((str[i] == ')') && (flag == 1))
    {
      flag = 2;
      break;
    }
} 

//тут по значению флага  определяете нашли вы скобку или нет, 
//по значению i определяете позицию скобки
```

Answer (score 1):

Если не нужно анализировать сбалансированность скобок, то проще всего использовать функции [strchr()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strchr)/[strrchr()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strchr) для поиска открывающей и закрывающей скобок.

Это можно оформить в виде, например, вот такой демо программки:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct pp {
  const char *lp, *rp;
};

// возвращает структуру с указателями на первую `(` и последнюю `)` скобки 
struct pp
str_get_parenthesis (const char *str)
{
  struct pp res = {strchr(str, '('), strrchr(str, ')')};

  return res;
}

int
main (int ac, char *av[])
{
  char *str = 0;
  size_t len;

  while (getline(&str, &len, stdin) != -1) {
    struct pp p = str_get_parenthesis(str);
    if (p.lp && p.rp && p.rp > p.lp)
      printf("%.*s\n", (int)(p.rp - p.lp + 1), p.lp);
    else
      puts("Can't locate (...)");
  }
  free(str);

  return puts("End") == EOF;
}
```

Немного изменив функцию и структуру данных результата поиска, можно искать наиболее сбалансированные скобки:

```
struct ppb {
  const char *lp, *rp;
  int cnt; // показатель баланса -- 0 все скобки закрыты
};

struct ppb
str_balanced_parenthesis (const char *str)
{
  struct ppb res = {strchr(str, '('), 0, 0};
  if (res.lp) {
    res.cnt = 1;

    for (const char *p = res.lp + 1; *p && res.cnt; p++)
      if (*p == '(')
        res.cnt++;
      else if (*p == ')') {
        res.cnt--;
        res.rp = p;
      }
  }

  return res;
}
```

Использовать можно так (аналогично примеру выше):

```
...
struct ppb p = str_balanced_parenthesis(str);
if (p.lp && p.rp)
  printf("cnt = %d [%.*s]\n", p.cnt, (int)(p.rp - p.lp + 1), p.lp);
else
  puts("Can't locate (...)");
....
```